# why is IIS redirecting URL to temp path

Tags: redirect, iis

Why is IIS redirecting my request from

http://edit.example.com/login.aspx

to

http://edit.example.com/(S(fct2ftjw4s41evr0cvflz00k))/login.aspx

This happens in development also, with the iis express and localhost.

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled in your browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is displaying session state in url.

Take a look at 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx

You need to set

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" />
```

In web.config file.

Comment: that solved it, first time I had ever seen this issue.

Comment: I think you should study session state in detail. There are many different modes available for session handling.